# Calculator problems that have nothing to do with math

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Why does Math.SE permit questions about calculators that have nothing to do with math, for instance [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4150167/how-to-fix-the-the-calculator-cursor-moving-by-32258065-to-a-normal-number-t)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126393/discussion-on-question-by-david-g-stork-calculator-problems-that-have-nothing-t).

Answer (score 7):

I revised the short wiki text (aka "usage guidance") for the [calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculator) tag as follows:

> Questions regarding calculators being used to solve math problems.  A clear statement of the math problem to be solved is required.

I'll add a long wiki write-up after surveying how the tag has been used historically.  Note that I've removed any mention of specific calculator models from the usage guidance.

Comment: I like it.  Thanks.  (+1)

Comment: +1 It might be nice if we made all the similar tags consistent. For example, the [tag:maple] tag currently reads "For questions involving the application of the program Maple to mathematics. NOTE: questions which focus primarily on the program Maple and not on its applications to mathematics are not appropriate for this site." This has the same underlying meaning, but is phrased completely differently.

Comment: Thank you for doing something reasonable without any backhanded insults.